# Django retrieve data from multiple tables without foreign key relationship

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I have the following three Models

```
class Post(models.Model):
    category_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    participant_id = models.IntegerField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Instrument(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Here category_type in Post model can be "book" or "instrument" and these categories can increase in the future.

The participant_id column in Post table references the primary key of either Book table or Instrument table based on the category_type.

Now I want to retrieve all the posts and associated data from database.

In MySql, I can do it like this

```
select post.title,book.title from post,book where ((post.category_type="book" and post.participant_id=book.id))
union
select post.title,instrument.title from post,instrument where ((post.category_type="instrument" and post.participant_id=instrument.id))
```

But I am unable to do it using django as I cannot have foreign key relationship.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Update: I tried with Django's generic relations by modifying the Post table as below

```
class Post(models.Model):
    category_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    participant_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    participant_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'participant_id')    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And then I issued the following query

```
Post.objects.filter(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Book))
```

But this gives me error

```
FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'content_type' into field. Choices are: category_type, id,  participant_id, title
```

How can I retrieve the data if I cannot specify it in the condition.

Comment: You might be interested in [Django's generic relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#generic-relations) which allow you to create relationship between different models

Comment: Hi Timmy, I tried using Django's generic relations but using that I am not able to retrieve the results. Only if I know the particular book object before hand, then its useful. But I couldn't figure out how to retrieve the data using this generic relationship

Comment: The error looks like you didn't rebuild the DB

Comment: Yes that was the problem. I deleted the tables and did syncdb and the above mentioned method worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used Django's generic relations as suggested by Timmy. Following is the modified model for Post

```
class Post(models.Model):
    category_type = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    participant_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    participant_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'participant_id')    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And then I issued the following query

```
Post.objects.filter(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(Book))
```

This gave me the correct results
Don't forget to rebuild your DB after modifying the model otherwise you will get error.